# How to change the order of windows in grub

Tags: grub2

[image: Screenshot]

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02 beta2-9ubuntu1.3
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Memory test
Memory test serial console 115200
Windows 8 (Loader)
```

Recently I decided to install Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 in different partitions. They both work. The problem is that I want that the windows run with no key before 5 seconds, or put it the first.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of is to use Grub Customizer. Youu will have to add the repo first before installation:

This PPA contains the latest release of Grub Customizer.

Simply run these in terminal:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

You can then launch it by pressing super key and type grub customizer or I assume in terminal sudo grub-customizer

Mine looks like image below atm. You will be able to change many things in your grub loader. I find that clicking save after making the changes does not write them to the grub loader, but rather clicking on File and then "Install to MBR" does what I needed. Hope this helps.

My current Grub loader

[image: Screenshot]